# Jquery : animate image from right corner once scrolled to specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

i've to animate an image form right side. when page scrolls down its invisible and when page reaches there image floats from right now  i can detect the position of the scroll like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var target = $(".myimages").offset().top;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= target) {
        alert("image found ");
        //here float the image 
    }
}, 250);
  });
```

now i want to do is  float the image from right corner to its width. i only know its can use animation like this

```
   $('.myimages').animate({css properties here})
```

but don't know how to use it so please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is jQuery API for `animate` function: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

and some example how to use it:

```
$( ".myimages" ).animate({
    right: "100px",
    width: "200px"
}, 1000);
```

Post your working code on jsfiddle, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use.

by default use css3 transform to place it to the right

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  initAnimation();
});

function initAnimation() {
  var win = $(window);
  var targetImage = $('.myimages');

  var animate = function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= targetImage.offset().top) {
      targetImage.addClass('active');
    }
    else {
      targetImage.removeClass('active');
    }
  };

  win.on('load scroll', animate);
}
```

```css
.myimages {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.myimages.active {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```